# Google ignores hreflang metatag for my websites homepage

Tags: seo, google-search, hreflang

We implemented hreflang attribute to make sure search engines indexing made properly for global users. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077

It seems to be working for all our site pages except our homepage. Although we include the following tags, we see Turkish homepage result when we search by `domainname` in `google.co.uk`.

```
 <link rel="alternate" hreflang="tr-TR" href="https://www.domainname.com/" />
 <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="https://www.domainname.co.uk/" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate top level domains, you can set geo targeting in Google search console.

1. Add each of your domains to Google Search Console: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en
2. Set the country targeting for each site: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en

When I have done this in the past, it has prevented the sites from appearing outside their targeted search results extremely well.   I've preferred the setting in search console over hreflang tags because it is easier to implement, and very effective.

Comment: Sound advice. I'll briefly add that this covers Google, but if traffic is coming from other search engines like Bing and Yandex, this will have to be replicated in the webmaster tools for each one. Also, I'd recommend making sure that the lang meta tag is set to the proper language code, in the html tag at the top of the page.